# jquery simpleGrid disable when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an simpleGrid like that:

```
                     t.p.operatorGrid = $("#codGrid").simpleGrid({
                        dataUrl: t.p.operatorUrl,
                        columns: [
                            {name: "id", hidden: true},
                            {name: "cod", label: "Cod", width: "10%"}
                        ],

                        onSelectedCustom: function () {
                            t._enableButton(t.p.removeButton);
                        }
                    });
```

How can I show an loading box when my grid is loading data from server and disable the dialog so the user can't search something while the grid is loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can get loading image using simple gif . show while data is loading , hide on completion. and can disable the dialog using

> $(selector).attr('disabled','disabled');

See below code in action , hope it helps :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#change").on("click", function() {
    var req = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "datapro.php",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#wait").css("display", "block");
      },
      complete: function() {
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```css
#wait {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 89px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  '

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txt">
  <div id="result">jQuery Ajax Loading Animation</div>
</div>
<p></p>
<button id="change">Change Content</button>
<div id="wait">
  <img src='https://www.drupal.org/files/loading.gif' />
  <br />Please Wait While Loading Data ...</div>
```

Comment: I have to use the div into the js:
var wait = $("<div id='wait'><img src='https://www.drupal.org/files/loading.gif' /><br />Please Wait While Loading Data ...</div>");
How can I show the div? because
wait.css("display", "block");
does not work... neither $("#wait").css("display", "block");

Comment: even if you are using in js , still you need to append it to some element in tag . it should work once it's in dom.